# Excel Title Row -- Not part of the count when using conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to set my Excel document to color every tenth line in the document using conditional formatting -- without counting the header row as row 1.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula in the conditional formatting. I assumed row 1 is the header row.

```
=MOD(ROW(),10)-1=1
```